# how to start executable from command line in windows

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I have a program when I click it, it opens fine.But when I run it command prompt it gives an error that is related to a dll that my program uses.I do in cmd

```
"Path_to_program\program.exe"
```

And a note:my program is installed my D: drive

But it gives an error related to dll.the dll is in the same directory with program.I guess it is related to dll.is there an option to give the dll as dependency to my command?

Comment: try to go to the directory first, then execute the program from there : `cd "Path_to_program" & program.exe`

Comment: thank you it was a bad question:)I have forgetten it.

Comment: Delete the question or mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to the same folder that the program is in so that your working directory matches.

Try

```
cd Path_to_program
program.exe
```

Comment: Also `start "" /D "Path_to_program" "program.exe"`.

Comment: @redx This would be better as `cd /d "Path_to_program"` so it changes drive and also allows long pathname elements.  Likewise `"program.exe"` is better in quotes, so anyone searching in future will have a solution that just works.